# Password confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, confirmation

How can I validate the confirmation of the password? So that the user get an error if the passwords don't match together. Same as the function "validates_presence_of" gives errors out whether the field is empty.
Sadly doesn't work this code for me.

```
<div class="field_left">
  <%= f.label :password, "Password" %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password retry<span>*</span>".html_safe %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</div>

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation
  attr_accessor :password
end
```

Can someone help me?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I get no error but it just doesn't work.

Comment: try "attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation"

Comment: please post the complete content of views/users/_form.html.erb and the associated controller action. also tell us **what you are trying to achieve**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I implemented the method new so:

```
@user = User.new (:last_name => params[:user][:last_name], :first_name => params[:user][:first_name] and so on.
```

Instead of:

```
@user = User.new(params[:user]
```

then it **works** with

```
validates_confirmation_of :password
attr_accessible :password_confirmation
attr_accessor :password
```

Answer (score 2):

Code from my app that work fine:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_confirmation_of :password
  attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation
  attr_accessor :password
end
```

You must set attr_accessor :password

Answer (score 1):

Before anyone can answer your question properly you have to explain clearly what doesn't work. Simply saying it "doesn't work" is not going to help you get the answer you need. Please explain clearly what you expect to happen and then explain what actually happens, backing it up with relevant information such as log file entries and relevant source code.

If you can provide this info I'll happily update this answer to point you in the right direction.

**Update**

You need an authenication method for your user.
There are many ways to do this and it all depends on how you encrypt your password.
Can I suggest you watch this Railscast. It explains one very good way to authenticate your user and is pretty much the defacto Rails way, used by many gems such as Devise

http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Comment: I updated the text. I hope now it is understandable.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing:

```
attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation
```

frank blizard is right about it

Comment: I tried it with "attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation" but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your user.rb does not have `attr_accessor :password_confirmation`. You'll need that in addition to the `attr_accessible` whitelisting.

Comment: Please update your current code in the question along with the specific error you are seeing.